Correct way to store .gitattributes (working-tree-encoding) after many commits?
There is a large Git repository (~4,000 commits) containing files in CP866 and does not contain a file named .gitattributes in the root of project. Is there any way to add .gitattributes (*.txt text working-tree-encoding=CP866) with rewriting everything as if it existed from the beginning?
Tried git rebase -i --root and got conflicts on every commit after adding .gitattributes in root.

Do you want Git to store the files internally in UTF-8 or should it keep CP866? If the latter, setting working-tree-encoding is not the right choice.

@j6t working-tree-encoding automatically converts between internal UTF-8 and file encoding.

@phd Yes, that's exactly the point. If Git should store files internally in CP866, then working-tree-encoding cannot do the conversion correctly, because it expects that Git stores them in UTF-8 internally. If OP still wants to use the services of working-tree-encoding, then they must also convert the data stored internally by Git. (And that will cause an undelightful mess of conflicts with git rebase.)

@j6t working-tree-encoding tell Git the encoding of a file in the working directory. If a file with this attribute is added to Git, then Git re-encodes the content from the specified encoding to UTF-8. Finally, Git stores the UTF-8 encoded content in the index. On checkout the content is re-encoded back to the specified encoding. So, I need CP866 in working tree and UTF-8 in index. And I'm ready to rewrite whole history, but don't  know correct way.

In this case, it is better when you do not use git rebase, because you will get conflicts at every file that is modified. You are better off with git filter-repo. I haven't studied its manual, but I assume it offers some way to rewrite the file content.

git rebase certainly should give conflicts on every commit due to different encoding. I couldn't find a simple way to use git filter-repo: its --blob-callback knows the data but doesn't know the file name which we should match against the mask *.txt; --commit-callback knows the files but only provides blob IDs so the content must be extracted and written separately.
So the following solution uses git filter-branch. I use --index-filter, it's much faster than --tree-filter (on 4000 commits it still will be slow, alas) and we have all the information in the index — file names and content. What the code does: first it creates new .gitattributes, then it runs a loop over all *.txt files recursively, convert them from CP866 to UTF-8 and updates the index. At the end it forces checkout of the converted files in the proper encoding. I took the main part of code from the answer, thanks @jthill! Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-filter-branch%5D+file+content
Before running any code please make a backup or run the code in a temporary copy of your repository!
Here is the code:
#! /bin/sh
set -e

FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --index-filter '
set -e
f=.gitattributes
updated=$(
    echo "*.txt working-tree-encoding=cp866" |
        git hash-object -w --stdin --path=$f
)
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,$updated,$f

for f in $(git ls-files "*.txt"); do
    updated=$(
        git cat-file blob ":$f" | iconv -f cp866 -t utf-8 |
            git hash-object -w --stdin --path="$f"
    )
    git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,$updated,"$f"
done
' HEAD

# Checkout the files in the proper encoding
find . -name "*.txt" -delete
git restore "*.txt"

I tested it on my repository https://github.com/phdru/m_librarian ; only converted README.rus.txt from KOI8-R to UTF-8. The real code I used is:
#! /bin/sh
set -e
cd m_librarian

FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --index-filter '
set -e
f=.gitattributes
updated=$(
    git cat-file blob :$f |
        sed "s!/README.rus.txt encoding=utf-8!/README.rus.txt working-tree-encoding=koi8-r!" |
        git hash-object -w --stdin --path=$f
)
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,$updated,$f #&&

f=README.rus.txt
if ! git cat-file blob :$f | iconv -f utf-8 -t koi8-r >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    updated=$(
        git cat-file blob :$f | iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 |
            git hash-object -w --stdin --path=$f
    )
    git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,$updated,$f
fi
' b4c32de..master

# Checkout the file in the proper encoding
rm README.rus.txt
git restore README.rus.txt


Instead of git show ":$f", it might be safer (and more idiomatic in a script) to use git cat-file blob ":$f", because git show may look at an existing .gitattributes file and attempt a conversion.

@j6t Thanks! Do you mean --textconv? I think adding --no-textconv would be enough. I believe other conversions from .gitattributes are not applied in git show <file>. And in this particular case we know for sure there are no .gitattributes files.

Know for sure? OP may have experimented a bit and left behind a .gitattributes file. But you may be right that conversions are not applied anyway. I did not check.

@j6t That there are no .gitattributes — almost sure. That there are no .git/info/attributes — not sure, and hard to spot.

@phd Thanks! Tried first script and got errors:
Rewrite 79641594237a2b1eb96b782561eb5843f95d665e (1/10) error: .gitattributes: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: git update-index: --cacheinfo cannot add .gitattributes
Rewrite 7dd3be7a5511b3b2e1a96666024a86824e2a6eb1 (2/10) error: .gitattributes: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: git update-index: --cacheinfo cannot add .gitattributes
and so on...
Missed --add parameter in git update-index ?

@gitik git update-index --add: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---add

@gitik I tested only on repositories where .gitattributes were already exist, I only rewrote them, never added, hence the omission. :-)

@phd Thanks, it works now! But very slow on big repos. I wanna try another way - via patch format like this git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- > /tmp/patch; iconv -f cp866 -t utf-8 /tmp/patch > /tmp/patch-reencoded; cd ../; git init new_repo; cd new_repo; git am  < /tmp/patch-reencoded
Or Is it bad idea?

@gitik With this you reencode the entire patch, not just the text files; let's hope you don't reencode too much. Also you don't create .gitattributes so you will need to rebase once more.

@phd Yes, I am reencode the entire patch and it's good in my case. Also .gitattributes will be added at the last step

@gitik Well, if you are not afraid of re-encoding everything than my note about git filter-repo is not relevant: --blob-callback can be used to reencode all blobs. Something like this: git filter-repo --blob-callback 'blob.data = blob.data.decode("cp866").encode("utf-8")'
